# Boost geometry rtree find iterator for exact match of box

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

When inserting a new box into an rtree, I want to first check if an identical box is already in the tree. If it is, I want to just get that value, otherwise I'll need to insert a new value. What is the best (ie most efficient) way to do this?

I can do it by calling `nearest(box,1)`, then checking equality:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 1, bg::cs::cartesian> TPoint;
typedef bg::model::box<TPoint> TBox;
typedef std::pair<TBox, void*> TPair;
typedef bgi::rtree<TPair, bgi::quadratic<16>> TTree;

TTree::const_query_iterator findExact(const TTree& tree, const TBox& box)
{
    auto it = rtree.qbegin(bgi::nearest(box, 1));
    if(it == rtree.qend() || !bg::equals(it->first, box))
        return rtree.qend();
    return it;
}
```

Is that really the best (ie most performant) way to do this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe approach. I can easily imagine a situation which may not work:

State of Rtree with 2 boxes before inserting new one:

```
(0,2) --- (1,2)
  |    b    |
(0,1) --- (1,1)
  |    a    |
(0,0) --- (1,0)
```

so we have 2 boxes `a` and `b`. Now you call `nearest` prediacte with 1 as the number of results when you try to insert a new input box with the same geometry as `a` box. `distance` between input geometry and `a` is 0, but 0 is also for `distance(input,b)`. `nearest` is limited to return only one box - which one ? you don't know, if it returns `b` box, you insert duplicate of `a` into Rtree.

Safe method can be as follows:

1. get new input box
2. calculate its centroid
3. get ALL boxes from rtree which contain input centroid
4. iterate over returned boxes and call `equals` function on pair (box from rtee,input box)

To do it you can use [contains predicate](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/group__predicates/contains_geometry_const___.html) which uses [boost::geometry::within](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html) method. As input of `contains/within` you pass point - centroid, if it is discarded by compiler (i am not sure it can take point), you can extend point-centroid into small box to compile.

Comment: Ah; I didn't realize nearest worked that way with boxes, but I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved efficiently by combining three queries `covered_by`, `covers` and `satisfies`:

```cpp
const auto it = rtree.qbegin(
    bgi::covered_by(box) && 
    bgi::covers(box) &&
    bgi::satisfies([box](const TPair& item) { return item.first == box; }));
```

- `covered_by`: matches smaller boxes completely within the target-box.
- `covers`: matches bigger boxes that have the target-box completely within.
- `satisfies`: forces exact matches only.

Note that only using `satisfies` would result in a check of each element, resulting in `O(N)` instead of `O(log N)`. And combining both `covered_by` and `covers` allows the search to be aborted early even if there are many smaller boxes within the target-box. The `satisfies` is a final check, in case there are some rounding errors.

[Rtree Query Documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/queries.html)

[Covered-By documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/covered_by/covered_by_2.html)